# Wordpress Call to a member function set_return_url() on a non-object

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I have an error in a fresh Wordpress installation. Everytime I click on "Design -> Customize" I receive this error:

```
Call to a member function set_return_url() on a non-object in \wp-admin\customize.php on line 28
```

I have tested it with Wordpress version 4.5 and 4.6.1, and always got the same result.

I installed it local with XAMPP, first with the URL "localhost:8080" then with the URL "localhost.local". Everything works fine, instead of the click to customize...

Has someone had a similar error in the past?

Answer (score 0):

If your site works fine on `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, but error occur on sever, you can try to update the WordPress permalinks (`Settings->Permalinks`).

If you have you edited any line of code in the theme you use - revert back changes.

Also you can try to switch and use the other old default WordPress theme(s) like `TwentyFifteen` for example, in order to see if it works fine. Then try once by switching the theme to default WordPress theme.